# jQuery parseJson feedback on completion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('<? $data = file_get_contents('dev/cache/parsed.json'); $data = str_replace("'", "\'", $data); echo $data; ?>');
```

As I'm loading approx 500kb of data using this, I would like to provide feedback to site visitors when this loading is complete. My question is whether .ready() will fire after this data is loaded, or before? If it fires before (taking into account only DOM as I suspect), then can I add something at the end of my JS that will create an alert of some kind, indicating that the obj has finished being processed by the browser and it has no moved on to executing the alert event?

My overarching question is in regards to the way in which the browser executes the page and when certain events trigger. From my implementation, I basically need something that will fire only when the entire obj variable has been read by the browser and it is finished loading the page entirely. I'm not sure whether .ready will work here.

Cheers

Comment: JSON is a subset of JS literal syntax. Why are you forcing it into a string then parsing it to a JS object? Just use it as a literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there isn't asynchronous, it will block all JS execution until it is done.

Just put the code you want to run after it… after it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronous, not asynchronous operation, so there is no concept of adding a callback to it. It would be no different from just firing that callback manually the line after your `parseJson` line.

In other words, your code will block execution of all other JS while it runs.

Options:

- have it done by a WebWorker script instead. These, where supported, run using a separate CPU thread, and do not therefore block the execution of your main script or hinder the user's ability to interact with your app
- rather than PHP dumping the file's contents directly into your JS, as currently, load it over asynchronous AJAX. Then you could do a success callback once loaded, as you wish.